# User interface flash AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

since the Site seems to be pretty buggy i have to post my question below. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Hi guys

I'm new to flash and i want to create a GUI for my little game.
How can i create a start window where I can select stuff like how many objects to spawn or move speed of my character.

My first idea was to hide everything else on the stage until I click start.
Would that be right. Is the a better way. how to do this anyway. 
And where do i put my GUI script. Stage or extern class.

Comment: For games, putting all your assets on frame 2, your preloading code on frame 1, and your actual game movieclip on frame 3 is the accepted way because games are usually only 1 .swf file, see http://asgamer.com/2009/making-a-complete-flash-game-creating-understanding-the-preloader

Comment: Or see http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/04/22/tutorial-preloading-actionscript-3-as3-games-in-flash-cs3/

Comment: nice tutorials but im not exactly looking for a preloader...i just need some buttons to select how many objects to spawn and how fast the character should move..while i select this, anything else should be invisible

Answer (score 0):

Place your start button in the first frame and put your other elements in second frame. On click of the start button gotoAndPlay to next frame.